# What is ($\sqrt{-1}$ or $i$) $\cdot$ $\infty$

Tags: infinity

Let:

$x=\infty\cdot i$

$y = \frac{\infty}{i}$

Find $\ x\ $and$\ y.\ $

Does this even make sense? Would $x$ just be $\sqrt{-\infty}$?

I'm confused as to what's going on here.

Comment: Some time ago I answered a similar question. Maybe this helps you: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2547353/385702

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\infty$ is **not a number** then these expressions

- $x=\infty\cdot i$
- $y=\frac{\infty}{i}$
- $\sqrt{\pm\infty}$

are, in the usual context, meaningless.

In some cases, notably when we deal with limits, we can use expressions like:

- $\infty\cdot\infty$
- $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$
- $1^{\infty}$
- $i\cdot\infty$
- etc.

but they are to be intended as symbolic expressions with the aim to express, in a short term, whether an expression is or not in an indeterminate form.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding $i\cdot\infty$ to the list. In some contexts, for example when dealing with the upper half-plane, it serves a role as a "limit point at the end of the imaginary axis". Comes to the fore when dealing with modular forms and such. Admittedly it is unlikely to be relevant to the asker.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks so much for your kind contribution! And I have to admit that it is unlikely also to me but it is very stimulating to know! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

$x=\infty\cdot i$ is the most simplified it can get. It equals infinite imaginary things

$y= \frac{\infty}{i} = y = \infty \cdot -i$